# Problema setToken es nulo VIMEO API

Tags: php, javascript

Actualmente tengo el error al cual declarar mi librería VIMEO recibo un error de que el valor que recibe la declaración del Token es nulo.

**Mi codigo**

```
private $scope = "public*";
private $user_id_VIMEO; //'user96563971';
protected $lib;

    function __construct($client_id_VIMEO,
            $client_secret_VIMEO,$token_VIMEO,$user_id_VIMEO){

       //cargando libreria de VIMEO
       $this-> lib=new Vimeo($client_id_VIMEO, $client_secret_VIMEO/*,$token_VIMEO*/);
       $token = $this->lib->clientCredentials($this->scope);
        // use the token
       $this->lib->setToken($token['body']['f705fe71e021ed4bb73afa38e266a216']);

       $this->user_id_VIMEO=$user_id_VIMEO;


    }
```

Este código debería funcionar, el token es correcto y esta generado para la función `Unauthenticated`.

**Lo que me arroja la respuesta**

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Vimeo\Vimeo::setToken() must be of the type string, null given, called
>   in /storage/ssd1/102/9066102/public_html/ScriptVZS.php on line 39 and
>   defined in
>   /storage/ssd1/102/9066102/public_html/vimeo/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php:171
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /storage/ssd1/102/9066102/public_html/ScriptVZS.php(39):
>   Vimeo\Vimeo->setToken(NULL) #1
>   /storage/ssd1/102/9066102/public_html/index.php(23):
>   ScriptVZS->__construct('beaac3cb5e4f0ab...', 'MhTBAXXc63DjmZi...',
>   '7c13e3d84db3da1...', 'user96563971') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /storage/ssd1/102/9066102/public_html/vimeo/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php on
>   line 171

**Gracias y espero su apoyo**

Comment: el error te esta diciendo que el valor que hay en `$token['body']['f705fe71e021ed4bb73afa38e266a216']` es nulo. Me da que lo que tiene que asignar es `f705fe71e021ed4bb73afa38e266a216` y no el valor que hay dentro de esa clave. Podrias hacer un `var_dump($token); die(); ` antes del setToken para ver como esta llegando ese array?

Comment: Revisa el token para ver qué hay dentro: `var_dump($token);`

Comment: Tenia razón existía cierto inconveniente con este token, pero encontré una mejor forma de declarar el token un poco mas conveniente a mi necesidad de desarrollo que es un script.

Answer (score 0):

Por fin encontré una solución, que es una alternativa a usar:

```
    $vimeo = new Vimeo($clientId, $clientSecret);

    // Set access token
    $vimeo->setToken($access_token);
```

Esta forma alternativa la encontré [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891474/vimeo-php-api-make-authenticated-request) y consiste en generar mi propio token y utilizarlo directamente.